# How do I get the frame size? - AutoLayout

Tags: swift3, autolayout

If implementing AutoLayout in UIView with code, what i get the size of the width of the frame of UIView?

```
        mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.view.addSubview(mainView)
        mainView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        mainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true

print(mainView.frame.width)//0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by getting the size of the view after the layout was drawn in the view

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(mainView.frame.width)
}
```